# Plotting Multiple Curves for Number of Movies By Genre Per Year

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to complete the following task:

> For each of the first 6 genres (not including short movies) consider
> only movies from 1990 until the last year recorded and plot a function
> of the number of movies in this data base of corresponding genre
> produced by year, for years from 1990 until the last year recorded.
>
> For each of the 6 genres you should have one curve, and plot all the
> curves in the same figure. Naturally, use different colors, and
> appropriate legend.

I have to rely primarily on the dplyr package to come with a solution. Here are the packages needed:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2movies)
```

Answer (score 1):

A smaller solution:

```
db=ggplot2movies::movies %>%
  filter(year >= 1990 & Short == 0) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(18:23), names_to='Genre',values_to='Genre_Bool') %>%
  select(year,Genre,Genre_Bool) %>%
  group_by(Genre,year) %>%
  summarise(Total=sum(Genre_Bool)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=Total, col=Genre)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try below - by the way there are other ways to do this more succinctly/briefly using reshape2 package for example to turn data frame from wide to long. Given that you are for some reason restricted to the packages you listed, below is a working code (not the most elegant but it works).

Also, there are cases where a movie gets assigned multiple genres - i added multi_genre_movie - in case you only want to consider movies from 1990 onward that only have one movie genre, you can uncomment the line of code in the middle of the code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2movies)

# a lot of movies are classified under multiple genres, crating a multi_class_genre feature
movie_aggregate <- 
  ggplot2movies::movies %>%
  filter(year >= 1990 & Short == 0) %>%
  select(
    Action,
    Animation,
    Comedy,
    Drama,
    Documentary,
    Romance,
    year
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    multi_genre_movie = if_else(
    sum(c_across(Action:Romance)) > 1, 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  # filter(multi_genre_movie == 0) %>%  # remove first # in this line if you only want the movies with one genre class only
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(
    action_n = sum(Action),
    animation_n = sum(Animation),
    comedy_n = sum(Comedy),
    drama_n = sum(Drama),
    doc_n = sum(Documentary),
    romance_n = sum(Romance),
    multi_genre_movie_n = sum(multi_genre_movie)
  )
  
  
ggplot(movie_aggregate, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = action_n, colour = "action")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = animation_n, colour = "animation")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = comedy_n, colour = "comedy")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = drama_n, colour = "drama")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = doc_n, colour = "doc")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = romance_n, colour = "romance")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = multi_genre_movie_n, colour = "multi_genre_movie")) +
  ylab("count") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2005, 2)) + 
  ggtitle("Movie Counts By Genre Over Time") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```